# invalidateQUeries not working if one of url params change

Tags: next.js, react-query

I get a list of data by react query and show in a table. the table has pagination and data count to show in a page.

```
const {push, query} = useRouter();
const {page = 1, size = 10, ordering} = query;
const {data: response, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, isFetching} = useQuery({
   queryKey: ['getServers', page, size, ordering],
   queryFn: () => getServersService({pageSize: +size, page: +page, sorting: ordering as string})
});
```

Each row of table have delete icon to remove that icon  by calling delete api

```
const {push, query} = useRouter();
const {page = 1, size = 10, ordering} = query;
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const {data:deleteResponse, mutate, isError, isSuccess:successDelete} = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (id:number) => deleteServerService(id),
    onSuccess: () => {        
        queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: ["getServers", page, size, ordering]});
    },
});
```

If I change the page, or change the number of results in the table, or sort a column of the table (by doing any of these things, the parameter of the load address will change), after removing a row from the table, invalidateQueries does not work properly. While if I don't do any of these things, everything is ok and after deleting, the list will be updated correctly. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["getServers"] })
```

This would invalidate all queries with query key of `['getServers', ...]` regardless of what comes after it, so it your case regardless of `page`, `size` or `ordering`.

Comment: I do that but not work correctly again